# Getting "No standard config is available" when running Openai "gym retro"

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I am getting the "NoSuchConfigException: No standard config is available" from pyglet when running Openai "gym retro" on Google colaboratory, running xvfb as the x server.

Answer (score 0):

pyglet is an opengl library. I don't think you can have an opengl display interface. You can only use web-interface (Jupyter Notebook) with Google Colab.